# Threads at a distrubuted system in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to see whether there is an existing implementation for "distributed threads" in Java.

In our days almost everything is moved to cloud. So to say when I have a queue full o messages i can use a simple ThreadPoolExecutor and spawn various threads to take over. Off course all of them belong to the same VM (virtual machine).

What about when i have a system with 3 VMs ? Is there any framework that will support such a scaling without caring where the threads belong ? 
Let's say something like a distributed ThreadPool executor so the treads might belong to multipe VMs ?

Comment: You're looking for microservices, or AWS lamda maybe. A web search with these keywords should get you started. Read some, then come back and ask specific questions. As is, your question is probably too broad.

Comment: I am wondering whether a specific Distributed Executor Service is available and widely used ? I checked about Hazelcast Distributed Executor. Is it really what is ment to be or it doesn't scale along multiple vms? I mean is it operating only on master slave clusters ?

Comment: my mistake...wanted to add virtual machines !

Comment: Your question is generally ill defined: having a piece of code running on different hardware is not a problem, but having it run within the same JVM state is a problem without a general solution. You need to pick your trade-offs, what and how things will be synchronised to other machines. Having said that, there are virtual machine solutions that can unite multiple physical systems into one with many more CPUs etc and then the problem is solved automatically. But I guess the latter is not what you are talking about. The best solution for you will probably be any sort of messaging queue (MQ)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a messaging queue. and a simple (scalable) application that listens to that queue. you can then monitor the queue and scale up if things get busy.